# Is there reactjs have auto switch render? (renderToStaticMarkup, renderToString)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I render server and client side with same jsx. I need some element only have html, and do not need data-reactid. (e.g. A pure html jsx layout has some dynamic variable but do not need data-reactid).

And i except i can reuse the server side render dom which contains data-reactid, and do not need rerender the view.

The other element has data-reactid which can do not need rerender by reactjs. 
Cannot use `shouldComponentUpdate` because 'renderToString' method do not call `shouldComponentUpdate`.

I don't except i should render two element with different function( e.g. renderToStaticMarkup, renderToString) and combine it because the element could be include by many element. Render split and combine could cause mistake when element is much more.

Here is my fantasy:

In this case, i want {this.props.children} have data-reactid but the outside html and budy (DefaultLayout) do not.

```
class DefaultLayout extends  React.Component{   
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            return (
                <div>{this.props.children}</div>
            );
        } 
        return (
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="container" className='container'>
                    <div>{this.props.children}</div>
                </div>
                <script src='/js/index.js'type='text/javascript'></script>
            </body>
        </html>
        );
    }
};
DefaultLayout.noNeedDiffCompoment = true;
export default DefaultLayout;
```

or a new pure html Compoment

```
class DefaultLayout extends  React.PureHtmlComponent{    

        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            return (
                <div>{this.props.children}</div>
            );
        }
        return (
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="container" className='container'>
                    <div>{this.props.children}</div>
                </div>
                <script src='/js/index.js'type='text/javascript'></script>
            </body>
        </html>
        );
    }
};
export default DefaultLayout;
```

and i can use this layout easly and not error in client side and server side.

```
class Somepage extends  React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <h1>Hello world</h1>
            </DefaultLayout>
        );
    }
};
```

If i write as above, the render function can auto swap render function to render elements.

Is there any graceful solution like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case you should use the famous [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) instead of `props.children`.

There's no other solution.

```
const DefaultLayout = ({html}) => (
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container" className='container' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html} />
            <script src='/js/index.js'type='text/javascript'></script>
        </body>
    </html>
);
export default DefaultLayout;
```

and...

```
const html = renderToString(<App />);
return renderToStaticMarkup(<DefaultLayout html={html} />);
```

Comment: Thanks replay, but i want this jsx template can render server side and client, so i add some code to show it more clearly.

Comment: There is why i used props.children. If there has no other solution I'll try to write a express middleware to do that.

Comment: You can use the same `<App />` component for both client and server. You can't use the `<DefaultLayout />` one because it doesn't make sense. client-side components can't contain an `<html>` tag. This is the only way I can think of.